# Update Maven Project to Java 17 in Eclipse 2022-03 is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a pristine `Eclipse 2022-03` with `JRE's 1.8 & 17` defined under `Windows 10`.

Having created a new Maven Project I tried `Maven/Update Project...` but it has no effect: the JDK remains 1.8.

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk17.project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JDK 17 Project</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I then changed it to:

```
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk17.project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JDK 17 Project</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This worked, the JDK was updated to 17. However, I find it rather long-winded.

Anyone know why the other pom is not working?

Addendum: the following 2 JRE's are configuered

- 1.8 Oracle + unlimited Crypto
- 17 openJDK (Zulu Release with JavaFX bundled)

[image: JRE's]

Addendum: Maven settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
  <mirrors/>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>java8</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Addendum: Project/Java Compiler

[image: Project/Java Compiler]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Both given examples works fine for me in Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23).

Comment: It works for me on another machine using Eclipse 2021-09, but I can't find out how to reproduce that now, as that version needs "Java 17 Support for 2021-09" from the Marketplace & that has been removed.

Comment: Maybe an environment variable? The Maven Console output for both the <build> & <properties> methods are identical.

Comment: It works in the current version of Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23) which has built-in Java 17 support. Your assumption that it is not working in Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23) is not reproducible. Double-check your given example in a fresh workspace with a fresh project.

Comment: It is fresh: Downloaded from eclipse.org, unzipped, fired up with a new workspace & just this one project. Its also happening with Eclipse 2021-12. As I just mentioned (above), I can't check it with 2021-09 as the necessary "Java 17 Support for Eclipse 2021-09" (which used to be in the Marketplace) has been removed.

Comment: What do you have configured in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_?

Comment: Have added JRE-Config Screenshot to original Posting

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Could you please try it with a fresh workspace without copy the setting (_File > Switch Workspace > Other..._). In a fresh workspace you should see only the in Eclipse embedded Java 17 in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_. Please show also what you have in _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_ after you right-clicked the project and chosen _Maven > Update Project..._

Comment: After BOTH "Switch Workspace" & Exit/Restart, new Maven Project & "Maven/Update Project" -> "Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1,8' (which yields a warning as the only JRE available is the builtin eclipse 17.0.2 hotspot.

Comment: When creating a Maven project, you skipped archetype selection, right? Please show what you have in _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_, tell whether do you have a `settings.xml` file in your local Maven `.m2` directory and if you have one, show its content.

Comment: Yes, I skipped archetype selection. The settings.xml file is unchanged for the last 5 years, but with my Eclipse Mars (v4.5 from 2015 it still works fine). See Addendum to original Posting for contents.

Comment: Does it work when deleting the `settings.xml` file?

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.  Can I leave it like that or do I need a more up-to-date settings.xml?

Comment: You can leave it like that since there is no `settings.xml` file needed. If you are sure that `settings.xml` should not override the `pom.xml` here, please [report it to m2e](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues).

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "If you are sure that settings.xml should not override the pom.xml here". Could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: I wasn't sure if this is an issue of m2e or of Maven or whether this is the behavior of Maven, which seems counterintuitive to me. So I created a record and run `mvn clean install` with and without your `settings.xml`: it fails with `settings.xml` and works without `settings.xml`. That proves it's not an issue of m2e, but either an issue of Maven 3.8.4 (which is embedded in Eclipse 2022-03 and probably used here) or the expected behavior of Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **caused by your Maven `.m2/settings.xml`** file which overrides the properties of your `pom.xml` file.

Maven on the command line also behaves this way (you can test this e.g. with a record: with your `settings.xml` file the build fails and without your `settings.xml` file the build will be successful).

**Rather set the Java version in each parent `pom.xml`** file **than** the (default) Java version **in your Maven `.m2/settings.xml`** file this way.

Comment: I now remember why I put the Java version in settings.xml all those years ago: it was an attempt to get Eclipse to configure new Projects with that version, rather than museum version 1.5 which was (and still is today!!) the default.

Comment: Eclipse follows Maven's specification here: a Maven project created today, does not mean that it should be compiled with anything higher than Java 5. Independent of which IDE you use, the Java version has to be explicitly specified, since it is not derived from something.